How to keybind an org-capture template with use-package?
Suppose I bound org-capture with C-c c and a tmp template with t:
(setq org-capture-templates
    `(
      ("t" "tmp"
       entry (file ,(concat captures-path "tmp.org"))
       "* %?" :empty-lines 1)
      ))

C-c ct opens tmp.
Now, if I want to add a new keybinding to tmp, for example C-c m, how could I refer to tmp? I.e., in the following example, what would replace ????
(use-package org-capture
  :bind 
  ("C-c m" . ???)
  )


This should do the trick:
(use-package org-capture
  :bind 
  ("C-c m" . (lambda () "Open tmp capture window"
               (interactive)
               (org-capture nil "t"))))

